# How to store point (x, y) in a database?

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I need to store location (x,y point) in my database where, point can be null and `X` and `Y` are always less then 999. At the moment I'm using EFCore Code First and Postgresql database, but I'd like to be flexible so that I can switch to MSSql without too much work. I'm not planning to move away from EF Core.

Right now, I have two columns: `LocationX` and `LocationY`, both are `int?` type. I'm not sure if this is good solution, because technically DB allows (X=2, Y=null), and it's should be. It's either both are null, or both are not.

My option two is to store it in a one string column: *"123x321"*, with max length of 7.

Is there a better way?

Thanks,

Comment: Why not use a [point](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-geometric.html)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name oh, I wasn't aware of such type. Uhh.. but why it takes 16 bytes?? With two smallint columns I can store the one point on 4 bytes

Comment: Geometric types are supported in a uniform way across PostgreSQL and MSSQL. See [Spatial Data in EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/modeling/spatial). They enable more powerful queries than simple X and Y values do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check constraint could be used to enforce both column are NULL or NOT NULL at the same time:

```
CREATE TABLE t(id INT,
  x INT,
  y INT,
  CHECK((x IS NULL AND y IS NULL) OR (x IS NOT NULL AND y IS NOT NULL))
);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a17ff83665ba655294b817a92bc08e9c)**

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the check constraint suggested by @LukaszSzozda you can restrict the x,y values with an additional check constraint on each. So assuming they must also be in range 0,999 then

```
CREATE TABLE t(id INT,
  x INT constraint x_range check ( x>=0 and x<=999),
  y INT constraint y_range check ( y>=0 and y<=999),
  CHECK((x IS NULL AND y IS NULL) OR (x IS NOT NULL AND y IS NOT NULL))
);
```

As far a your idea of storing a single string - **very bad**. Not only will you have the issue of separating values every time you need them it allows for distinctly invalid data. Values '1234567' and even 'abcdefg' are completely valid as far as the database is concerned.
So your table definition must account for and eliminate them. With this your table definition becomes:

```
create table txy
           ( xy_string varchar(7) 
           , constraint xy_format check( xy_string ~* '^\d{1,3}x\d{1,3}') 
           )
insert into txy(xy_string) 
  ( values ('1x2'), ('354X512'), ('38x92') );
```

Which is actually a reduction as it is back to a single constraint, but your queries now require something like:

```
select xy_string 
     , regexp_replace(xy_string, '^(\d+)(X|x)(\d+)','\1') x 
     , regexp_replace(xy_string, '^(\d+)(X|x)(\d+)','\3') y
from txy;
```

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=034094b52f42713a5d5e91ecbec23379) here.

In short never store groups of numbers values as a single delimited string. The additional work is just not worth it.